# How to write a Python rectangle class?

Tags: python

So I am trying to do this:

Create a class named `Rectangle` with the following attributes and methods (sample run for each method included):

1. Each instance should have an x, y, width, and height attributes.
2. You should be able to pass the attributes when creating the rectangle as follows, (where x=5, y=10, width=50, height=100 in that order):

   ```
   r = Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)
   ```
3. Create a method that returns the rectangle as a string (hint: implement **str** ). For a rectangle object with attribute values x=5, y=10, width=50, height=100, it should return the string `Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)`.

   ```
   >>> r2 = Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)
   >>> print(r2)
     Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)
   ```
4. Create a method called `right` that gets the value of the right edge of the rectangle. It should take no arguments:

   ```
   >>> r3 = Rectangle(3, 5, 10, 20)
   >>> r3.right()
     13     

   >>> r4 = Rectangle(12, 10, 72, 35)
   >>> r4.right()
     84
   ```
5. Create a method called `bottom` that gets the value of the bottom edge of the rectangle.

   ```
   >>> r5 = Rectangle(5, 7, 10, 6)
   >>> r5.bottom()
     13      

   >>> r5.y += 12    
   >>> r5.bottom()
     25
   ```
6. Create a method called `size` that returns the width and height of your rectangle.

   ```
   >>> r6 = Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4)
   >>> r6.size()
     (3, 4)
   ```
7. Create a method called `position` that returns the x and y coordinates of your rectangle.

   ```
   >>> r6.position()
     (1, 2)
   ```
8. Create a method called `area` that returns the area of your rectangle.

   ```
   >>> r6.area()
     12
   ```
9. Create a method called `expand` that takes an offset value and returns a copy of the rectangle expanded with offset in all directions.

   ```
   >>> r = Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)
   >>> r    
     Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)

   >>> r1 = r.expand(offset=3) 
   >>> r1    
     Rectangle(27, 37, 106, 116)
   ```

   The original rectangle should not be modified.

   ```
    >>> r
     Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)
   ```

   Negative values should return a shrunken rectangle.

   ```
   >>> r.expand(-5)
     Rectangle(35, 45, 90, 100)
   ```

I can not figure out number 9 but I believe I am doing other things correct here is what I have so far:

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, X, Y, W, H):

       self.x = X

       self.y = Y

       self.w = W

       self.h = H

    def complete(self):
        return self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h

    def right(self):
        return self.x + self.w

    def __str__(self):
        return('Rectangle(' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ','
                    + str(self.w) + ',' + str(self.h)+')')
    def bottom(self):
        return self.y + self.h

    def __str__(self):
        return('Rectangle(' + str(self.y) + ',' + str(self.h) + ','
               + str(self.y) + ',' + str(self.h) + ')')
    def size(self):
        return self.w,self.h

    def position(self):
        return self.x,self.y

    def area(self):
        return self.w * self.h

    def expand(self):
        pass

print(Rectangle(5,10,50,100).complete())

print(Rectangle(3, 5, 10, 20).right())

print(Rectangle(12, 10, 72, 35).right())

print(Rectangle(5,7,10,6).bottom())

print(Rectangle(1,2,3,4).size())

print(Rectangle(1,2,3,4).position())

print(Rectangle(1,2,3,4).area())
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Take care with your indenting, functions that you want to be part of the class need to be indented the same as `def __init__()`

Comment: It keeps giving me an error if I indent the rest though...

Comment: What is expected to happen to a `Rectangle` that has `expand(-100)` called on it when `width()` is only 40?

Comment: I would guess not work? I need to just reduce by 5, I think I bit off more than I can chew with this..

Answer (score 0):

```
def expand(self,amt):
    x = self.x - amt # move left side out by amount specified
    y = self.y -  amt # move the top side up by the specified amt
    w = self.width + amt * 2 # make the width long enough so the left side and right side are both expanded by amount
    h = self.height + amt * 2 # make the height tall enough so both top and bottom are expanded  
    return Rectangle(x,y,w,h)
```

note that I didnt look too closely at your class ... your variables may be named different ... I also assume that in your actual code you have correct indentation ...

Comment: I know the defs should be indented but when I indent it tells me unexpected indent error and I cannot figure out why

Comment: Wait...got the indentions I am a fool

Comment: Joran, I got other parts working by fixing the indents but I cannot figure out how to define the amt, I need -5 but cannot get it to code right